# Не меняет на живые обои

Tags: python, pyqt

На гитхабе нашел движок отвечающий за смену обоев на живые прям, как платный аналог wallpaper enjine.
Ссылка на статью https://github.com/Francesco149/weebp
Написал код, пытался использовать QProcess, но ничего не происходило

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from script import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess
import sys

class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.runWallpaper)

    def runWallpaper(self):
        process = QProcess()

        args = ["run", "mpv", "--wid=66566", "Test.wmv", "--loop=inf", "--player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui", "--force-window=yes", "--no-audio"]

        # Приложение 'wp' должно быть прописано глобально, либо к нему должен быть указан путь
        process.start("wp", args);

        # ИЛИ
        # process->start("<путь/к/приложению/>wp", args);
        

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```